# SSRS Error Bar (Range) Chart not showing Y value (Central value)

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have setup an Error BarChart (in the Range chart grouping) like so:

[image]

[image]

Where my values are:
Center:

```
=Avg(iif(Fields!TYPE_CODE.Value = "STD APP", Fields!ACTUAL_REVIEW_TIME.Value, Nothing))
```

Lower:

```
=Min(iif(Fields!TYPE_CODE.Value = "STD APP", Fields!ACTUAL_REVIEW_TIME.Value, Nothing))
```

Upper:

```
=Max(iif(Fields!TYPE_CODE.Value = "STD APP", Fields!ACTUAL_REVIEW_TIME.Value, Nothing))
```

And the Marker Settings are 'Auto'.  And the Lower and Upper values are graphing the way I thought, but there is no obvious marker being generated for the Center value:

[image]

In fact, the errors barsaren't visualized in the way I would expect unless a Marker type of 'None' is chosen:
[image]

What should my Series and Cart Settings be to get the classic Error bar look?

Answer (score 0):

Change your chart type to box plot and you get the results I think you are after.

I created some very simple sample data as follows...

```
DECLARE @t TABLE( yr int, low int, hi int, av int)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(2010, 10, 20, 15),
(2011, 5, 20, 10),
(2012, 5, 30, 20)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then added a boxplot chart and set the series values to this...

[image]

By setting the low and high box values to the average, this shows as a line (a really thin box)

This is the result..

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think I should have to perform a work around as the example image of an error bar chart in SSRS shows a central value.  Besides, I already have a work around that produces what I want, but I don't think the work around should be necessary overall.